# Why is my phpMyAdmin page not interpreted from raw PHP code?

Tags: apache-2.2, mysql

I am quite new to website construction. I have been practicing with MySQL and phpMyAdmin before, but only on localhost. It went well. But when I actually bought myself a domain name and changed the document root of my Apache to some other directory (other than public_html and such), I found it's not working as I expected it to.

It happened when I was trying to manage my database from a remote client. I typed in the URL of `mywebsite/phpmyadmin`, it gave me a `404 error`. I ran a little research and found [this page](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1036836) and followed the instructions, added

```
Include /etc/phpmyadmin/apache.conf
```

to `/etc/apache2/apache2.conf`. It worked to an extent that I don't get the `404 error` any more. But it went more peculiar in that my website started downloading the raw php code file that looks will be rendered as my phpMyAdmin page, but the page is not showing.

Anyone help?

Comment: Oh I'm so sorry folks I forgot to provide my system info... Indeed I am running Ubuntu, 12.10. I can't try out the solutions right now, but I will as soon as I get back to my computers. Thanks guys! You are awesome! ^_^

Comment: Your apache server does not how to execute php code: http://stackoverflow.com/a/20740045/1566267
http://stackoverflow.com/a/18061391/1566267

Answer (score 1):

`/etc/apache2/apache2.conf` indicates a debian-ish distribution. Did you install the libapache2-mod-php5 and php5-mysql packages? And did you run `a2enmod php5`?

Comment: Yes I am running Ubuntu. It appears that I have indeed installed all the packages you mentioned, and all my other php files are functioning just fine. I don't think the php interpreter is the problem. :\

Comment: Same issue here